# How to get new generated file name on logrotate?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, logging, logrotate

I want to get new file name generated by **Logrotate** and run a script on it.
Logrotate has an event called **Postrotate()** with a parameter called '$1' but it returns the original path file name for example '/var/log/app/error.log' but I have to get a newly generated file name like '/var/log/app/error.log.1'.
So how can I find that?

Comment: Do you just want to make a new file, named "[original].1" every time, with the same ".1" extension regardless of what other files already exist or were created by logrotate? So just append ".1" to any name given? Or if logrotate creates a new file named "[original].N" then you want to know what that file's called? Would examining logrotat's own log file after it's finished be ok?

Comment: Thanks, @Xen2050, I want to get new file name created by Logrotate like "[original].N".

Comment: I'm not sure if logrotate can do that on it's own, or from it's config file (it can compress old log files). You could have a separate process/script just watching the log directory for newly created files?